# How do you unit test a trigger when you don't know the required fields?

Tags: apex, unit-test, trigger, app-development

This is another issue addressed largely towards app developers.

Let's say I write an insert trigger. When I write the test case for it, what I would normally do is create a new object, insert it, and validate that whatever my trigger is supposed to do actually happened.

However, people add custom requirements to sobjects all the time. If they add 3 custom fields to the opportunity object and make them required, my test will now fail to insert because I'm missing those required fields.

Is it possible to create a test that can navigate around this issue?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Customers can have validation on custom fields via validation rules and triggers, so handling that in your unit tests without customer intervention is next to impossible.  The first step to reducing issues is to have your test data populate all standard fields and ensure the data uses the most common formatting for your customer base (US style phone numbers and addresses for the US for example).

Beyond that you can use the new Reflection features added to Salesforce in Summer '12 to allow customers to create unit test data classes that can be used by your managed package.  Basically you define a test data generation interface and the customer creates an Apex class to generate data for you.  Here's an example of using Reflection in a similar manner on the DeveloperForce blog: http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2012/05/dynamic-apex-class-instantiation-in-summer-12.html

Using the method for unit tests run on install might be problematic as you'd have to have the customer create the class before they install your package and your package could only look for the class by name (or iterate through all default namespace classes and check for the correct interface).  However, it's no longer necessary for unit tests to run during installation for managed packages and by default they do not.

The Reflection method requires some coding knowledge on the customer side, but you could add a tool in your application to generate the custom unit test data class for the customer.

FYI, it's no longer necessary for managed package unit tests to succeed in customer orgs.  They're not required on install, they will no longer prevent deployment to production and they don't count as part of the customers unit test coverage percentage for purposes of deployment.  The only exception to that is if the customer uses ANT and sets the runAllTests parameter to true.

Comment: The idea of using Reflection for this didn't even occur to me when I first read that blog entry.  It took a customer feature request with this idea for the whole thing to click.  I'll be using it for allowing the customer to extend our product, beyond custom unit test data.

Answer (score 2):

You also might check out SmartFactory:

https://github.com/mbotos/SmartFactory-for-Force.com

Which is handy project for generating test data based on describes.

Answer (score 0):

The post [Managed Packages and Customer Validation Rules / Required Fields](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/AppExchange-Directory-Packaging/Managed-Packages-and-Customer-Validation-Rules-Required-Fields/td-p/172658) suggests it isn't currently possible, at least in relation to validation rules (circa 2010).

There is the idea [Ability to turn workflow/validation rules off when running tests](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrpCAAS).

Comment: Thankfully things have changed for the better since I made that post in the developer forums, see my answer above.

Comment: @E.J.Wilburn. Ha, I noticed that I was linking to a post by you. Yes, I think your answer is better (more current) and have voted as such. I might leave my answer here for reference.

Comment: I have been fighting the managed package/validation rule fight since 2007 or so now since DupeBlocker has triggers on Leads, Contacts and Accounts.  Good times...

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, Salesforce need to stop Validation Rules being added to production without requiring deploying, or at least a run of unit-tests to ensure they don't break existing unit tests. I asked a question on a similar top already - [Ignoring Validation rules when deploying code](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/63/ignoring-validation-rules-when-deploying-code) - and quite liked the approach there.

Answer (score 0):

By using the description methods in salesforce you should be able to determine what the required fields are dynamically. I tend to create a singleton static class to contain this information.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fieldsets_describe.htm

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately customers can add whatever complex validation rules they want, and it would be virtually impossible to write a test case that could dynamically adjust to any future scenario.

This often means a customer can break the build, and it can be difficult for you to fix (Since you can't really edit code in production with broken test cases)